# .htaccess перенаправление по ссылкам

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно настроить правило в .htaccess

У меня задача сделать перенаправление с ссылок такого вида

**myshop/www/category/3/**  на

**myshop/www/?controller=category&id=3**

Пробую прописать в правилах

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

**RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+) /$ /?controller=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]**

И не отрабатывает(( Error 404

Answer (score 0):

После Вашего кода в вопросе

```
RewriteRule ^myshop/www/category/3/$  myshop/www/?controller=category&id=3 [L]
```